# What does "%.7le " in printf means?

Tags: c++, c, printf

What does

```
fprintf(fp, "%.7le ", data);
```

means?

I don't know what "%.7le " is mean.

Thanks!

Comment: How far did you get with deciphering based on the info provided in the spec? E.g. here https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf Did you really not understand any part of the format specifier you quote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.7` is the precision and `le` means normal form.

```
double x = 0.012345678910;
printf("%.7lf\n", x);  // 0.0123457
printf("%.7le\n", x);  // 1.2345679e-02
printf("%.9le\n", x);  // 1.234567891e-02
```

**Edit**
See Eric Postpischil's unswer below, it's way more comprehensive than this one.

Comment: What do you mean they have the same expected output? 
One of them is `lf` and one is `.9` precision?

Comment: Right, thanks :) I corrected it.
Must've miscalculated the number of steps when writing the comment.

Answer (score 5):

`%` starts a conversion specification.

`.7` says to use a precision of seven digits after the decimal point.

`l` says to use a “longer” type than the default. For floating-point, this means `double` (which is longer than `float`).

`e` says to use exponential form: The number is converted to the style [-]*d*.*ddd*e±*dd*. That is, a minus sign if appropriate followed by a number followed by “e” to indicate an exponent, and then a signed number to indicate a power of ten. For example, “3.45e-13” represents 3.45•10<sup>−13</sup>. The first number is always produced with one digit before the decimal point and as many digits after it as specified by the precision. So `%.2e` converts 3.45, 34.5, and 345. to “3.45e+0”, “3.45e+1”, and “3.45e+2”.

### Notes

The meaning of the precision differs depending on the conversion performed. For integer conversions, it is the minimum number of digits printed. For `g` conversions, it is the number of significant digits.

For historic reasons, `float` arguments to `printf` are promoted to `double`, so floating-point conversions with and without `l` are the same: They expect a `double` argument. This is different with `scanf`, it takes a pointer to a `float` or `double`, and the `l` is needed to distinguish them.