# dynamically set decimal separator in number/string using c programming

Tags: c

i am facing problem while placing decimal point in my input string.please refer my code for better understanding.
Description:The field shall be eight (8) digits in width, right-aligned, zero-filled. Left most digit denotes the number of positions the decimal separator shall be move from the right.

Expected result should be like this :
example 1: 71234567
output     0.1234567

example 2 : 31234567
output :    1234.567

But when i run my code with above example i am getting below output.
output 1 : 0.123457
output 2 : 1234.567000

It should not need to append the zeroes in right hand side.why this is happening.could anyone please tell me.

Attached my code snippet:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
        unsigned char str[8] = "31234567";
        int num = atoi(str);  //Convert string to int
        printf("num = %d\n",num);
        int FirstDigit = num;
        num = num % (unsigned long)pow(10.0, (double)floor(log10(num)));
        printf("After removing 1st digit from number = %d\n",num);
        while(FirstDigit>=10)
        {
            FirstDigit = FirstDigit/10;
        }
        printf("Decimal position stored in FirstDigit = %d\n",FirstDigit);
        printf("Final value = %f",num/pow(10,FirstDigit));
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Treat input as a string starting with a digit, eg `"4abcdef"`

Comment: I need to understand what is wrong with my code. If anyone can tell us with modified code i would appreciate. thanks!

Comment: https://ideone.com/pJz5J0

Comment: Hi there, you are getting the default float formatting ... if you want a specific number of digits you'll need to use a different format string - e.g "%.2f" gives two positions after the decimal..   See (https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) or (https://stackoverflow.com/a/67457936/15310387) for more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For default **printf** gives 6 significant digits, if precision is not specified.

https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html

> g, G The double argument is converted in style f or e (or F or
> E for G conversions).  The precision specifies the number
> of significant digits.  If the precision is missing, 6
> digits are given; if the precision is zero, it is treated
> as 1.  Style e is used if the exponent from its conversion
> is less than -4 or greater than or equal to the precision.
> Trailing zeros are removed from the fractional part of the
> result; a decimal point appears only if it is followed by
> at least one digit.

In your case you are trying to print the number 0.1234567 but in that number there are 7 significant digits. So **printf** rounds that number to 0.123457. You can specify precision like this.

```
printf("Final value = %.7f",num/pow(10,FirstDigit)); // (%.7f)
```

But you also want to get rid of the trailing zeros. For this you can use it like this.

```
printf("Final value = %.10g",num/pow(10,FirstDigit)); // (%.10g)
```

I specified precison as 10 because you are using **int**. Hence **int** can have at most 10 digits.